# Connect to redis instance from Istio enabled pod in a EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, redis, istio, amazon-eks

I am running a EKS cluster with Istio enabled. I have launched an EC2 instance, where a redis server is running. EKS cluster and Redis both are in same VPC. All Inbound and Outbound rules allowed for both of them. But, When I am trying to access the redis instance inside of a pod, it is throwing "Connection reset by peer", while it is working fine from non-istio pod. What could be the reason ?

Istio Version :-

```
image: docker.io/istio/pilot:1.4.3
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
image: docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.4.3
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

I have also created a Serviceentry in that namespace .

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: svc-redis
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  hosts:
    - "redis-X.xxx.xxxx"
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - number: 6379
      name: http
      protocol: REDIS
  resolution: NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the Domain name as a host, so you need to set the resolution to `DNS`. Because When you set the resolution to `None`. It will try to connect to an IP address instead of using the domain name.

Here is my service entry for external Redis access.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: redis-svc
spec:
  hosts:
  - redis01.example.com
  ports:
  - number: 6379
    name: redis
    protocol: TCP
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

Comment: Try disabling mutual TLS.

Comment: Read this:
https://istio.io/faq/security/

You can disable in two way. Either globally or by using destinationrule.

Comment: Alright, I have created a Destionationrule as well with mtls mode diasabled

Comment: I will check and will get back to you dude. Don't you worry. istio is fun.